# error with Layout.alignment vertical bar in vertical bar .qml file

Tags: qt, qml

**Background**: I have a side project that I'm working on that's gonna be a "rolling" project that I'll be updating as I learn and grow as a programmer. Since this project will be growing with me I wanted to learn how to create a GUI that can be simple but also gives me the ability to really customize the GUI once I really feel comfortable with it. After feeling overwhelmed with options I landed on PySide6 and QML but I'm running into an issue with the QML file.

The tutorial I'm following is Python-QML integration (https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/qmlintegration/qmlintegration.html) and I'm using the .py and .qml files linked at the bottom of the tutorial page. For an IDE if it matters I'm using Pycharm and have PySide6 package added to the project as well as the QML Editor plug-in.

**Problem**: The issue that I'm having is with the .qml file. For some reason, it's not recognizing the vertical bar used in the two-dimensional flag to center my RowLayout vertically and horizontally. When I hover my cursor over the vertical bar I get a tip saying that one of multiple different symbols like commas, parenthesis, or braces were expected but instead got '|'.

```
ColumnLayout {
    id: rightcolumn
    spacing: 2
    Layout.columnSpan: 1
    Layout.preferredWidth: 400
    Layout.preferredHeight: 400
    Layout.fillWidth: true

    RowLayout {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignHCenter

        Button {
            id: red
            text: "Red"
            highlighted: true
            Material.accent: Material.Red
            onClicked: {
                leftlabel.color = bridge.getColor(red.text)
            }
        }
    }
```

I feel like I've checked everywhere Reddit, stack overflow, the documentation on the QT site, but can't find anyone else that's experienced this.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that setting `Qt.AlignVCenter` in a child of a ColumnLayout doesn't make sense since Layouts only honor alignment orthogonal to the direction of their layout. So, setting a vertical alignment on a vertically oriented layout won't do anything.

In this case, since you've simplified the example (specifically, all of your layouts only have one child), you don't really need any layouts at all. Instead, I would convert the ColumnLayout to an Item and then anchor the Button in the center of it like this:

```
Item {
    id: rightcolumn

    Layout.columnSpan: 1
    Layout.preferredWidth: 400
    Layout.preferredHeight: 400
    Layout.fillWidth: true

    Button {
        id: red
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Red"
        highlighted: true
        Material.accent: Material.Red
        onClicked: {
            leftlabel.color = bridge.getColor(red.text)
        }
    }
}
```